# Why does this set get smaller as N increases?

Tags: real-analysis

In the Elementary Analysis book by Ross in the explanation of a $\liminf$ and $\limsup$ it states that as $N$ increases the set $\{s_n: n > N\}$ grows smaller. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example:

$N=10$, then $\{s_n|\; n>N\}=\{s_{11},s_{12},s_{13}...\}$

$N=100$, then $\{s_n|\; n>N\}=\{s_{101},s_{102},s_{103}...\}$

I think that says it all, because the second set is contained in the first one.

Comment: No problem. Generally speaking, examples are often the best way to check if and why unclear mathematical statements are true (or not).